# Jmeter returns 'The statement did not return a result set' for a SQL Query

Tags: jmeter

I have below SQL Query which is running fine in SQL Server but its showing error while executing in JMETER

```
declare @LogSpace table (DatabaseName varchar(255), [Log Size (MB)] float, [Log Space Used (%)] float, [Status] int) insert into @LogSpace execute('dbcc sqlperf(''LogSpace'')')  select cast(round([Log Space Used (%)],2,0) as decimal(18,2)) from @LogSpace where DatabaseName = 'PUB_SUB_E2E';
```

> Error: Response message:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not
>   return a result set.

I am using the JDBC Request Query Type as 'SELECT Statement'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per JMeter documentation:

> **JDBC Request**
>
> This sampler lets you send a JDBC Request (**an SQL query**) to a database.

In your case there are multiple queries of different nature which cannot be executed in a single shot. So the options are in:

1. Split the statement into separate queries so only a single query would be executed by a JDBC Request sampler
2. Convert your query into a [Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) and execute it using `Callable Statement`
3. Use [BEGIN and END statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to specify logical blocks
4. Move to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and write your queries in [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) (however you will still have to split it as suggested in the point 1 and use [execute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) function for parts which don't produce results and [executeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) for the parts which do.

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly fine. I just created a Stored Procedure and executed it using the Callable Statement. Thanks Dmitri for the answer.